# Why is entity framework giving this error on web server?

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, umbraco

I'm trying to use Entity Framework to add records to a database from a webform input that go into a database on sqlserver.
Everything works fine locally.

I used webmatrix to publish my site to my remote server, the website and my local version of the database is successfully recreated on the remote server with all the data.

However when it comes time to add records to the database, it gives an error on the remote server which i managed to trace to the ctx.Students.Add line.

```
        using (var ctx = new HDPS_SchoolDataEntities())
        {
            SchoolDataModel.Student temp = new SchoolDataModel.Student();

            temp.Name = this.FirstName;
            temp.Surname = this.Surname;
            temp.Parents = this.Parents;

            ctx.Students.Add(temp);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I can't find any difference between my local version that works and the one on the remote server that doesn't work. The web.config seems to be configured as expected and all the necessary dll's are in my bin folder but it just won't work on the remote server... any ideas what could be wrong?

Oops forgot the error message!

*edit*

after Installing .net 4.5 and changing the connection mode from windows authentication to SQL authentication the error now becomes:

Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development      may not work correctly if used in Code First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config file of executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then remove the code that throws this exception.

Everything should be the same on the webserver as the entire website is being copied across but it works fine locally so not sure what the problem is...

OKay I solved the issue with the help of this webpage

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/

In short It seems webmatrix was does not include the metadata part of the connection string on upload to the server thus the EDMX file containing all the information mapping the classes to the database tables was not being referenced causing any queries to the framework to fail.

Once i pasted the original connection string generated by the Entity Framework wizard onto the server everything worked fine.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: I thought the problem might be due to not having the .net 4.5 framework. After installing it the error changed to:

'code'Error Loading Razor Script (file: Application Form) The underlying provider failed on Open.    at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay I solved the issue with the help of this webpage

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/

It seems webmatrix was does not include the metadata part of the connection string on upload to the server thus the EDMX file containing all the information mapping the classes to the database tables was not being referenced causing any queries to the framework to fail.

Once i pasted the original connection string generated by the Entity Framework wizard onto the server everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error given in your comment, it sounds like you are failing to connect to the database.  Check your connection string, username and password.  If those are correct, make sure your database settings allows connections from your server ip address.